# Display "My Sites" first in the Android app's site list

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, android-app

When I expand the "All Sites" option in the Android app it would be nice, I think, if it listed the sites I belong to first and then list the rest of the sites (maybe alphabetically or as it is now minus the sites I belong to) with headers saying something like "My Sites" and "All Other Sites" for each list respectively.

[image]

Comment: I believe that it lists them in order of the amount of Rep you have.

Comment: @jeffreylin_ It can't since I am only registered on SO, MSO, and SU out of the above sites listed and that is the top of the list when I click "All Sites"

Comment: @jeffreylin_ It DOES list them by rep for the first 7 sites but then it goes into the "All Sites" overflow(?) option.

Comment: @jeffreylin_ unless it shows all sites that I have upvotes on (since it doesn't list associated bonus sites in the 7 shown, ones with 101 rep) in the area that I see 7 sites listed and then it puts the rest in the "All Sites" overflow.

Comment: This should **initially** be in the order of rep, but a **possibility reorder to a custom order** would be very good. There are sites that have a higher priority for me to read, but where I have lower rep.

Comment: Also see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192055/add-sites-to-the-sidebar-favorite-section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow this was left undiscussed for a while, sorry about that!

The list of "All Sites" is a static list of every site on the Stack Exchange network, sorted by when it was added to the network. I don't really want to make this a dynamic list, on top of having a dynamic list in the sidebar since it'll lead to a lot of confusion. When the list on the sidebar wasn't user editable this feature request made more sense, but I doubt it's relevancy today.