# Add sites to the sidebar favorite section

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, android-app

For now I see only the sites I already have some rep on, in the sidebar favorite section. But I want to add more site to it so that I can visit them easily without going to All sites > search.

On desktop I can just type a url and jump sites, it's not that easy on mobile. On mobile devices there should be an option where one can favorite sites. or else I'd have to search for the site every single time. It's not a browser so there is no tab either for quick access. Even a "last visited sites" section would do it.

TBH, that "favorite sites" section has different meaning for users with high and low reps. For users with higher reps, that section is more usable because they have already matured enough in a site to call it favorite. For users like me with lowers reps, it's hard to call them favorite. And the app is for everyone. Hence my suggestion.

Anything planned for this?

Comment: There's no footer in android-app?

Comment: Maybe I'm completely wrong here, but it seems to me like you'd really only be interested in visiting the sites where you are already a member when you're on the go. Having *all* the sites would just be needless clutter.

Comment: @Cody I think he means he want to be able to select which sites will appear there.

Comment: Yes. I'd like to choose which sites show up there. Like i have some rep in Skeptics site, but I hardly visit it now, it's certainly not one of my favorite sites.

Comment: Yeah, this is absoultely planned.

Comment: Also see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191284/display-my-sites-first-in-the-android-apps-site-list